# Woocommerce product attribute with multi select dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need Woocommerce single product with more than 1 attributes and user can select multiple attributes from each one. e.g. If I set attribute Color than user get dropdown for color and user can select more than 1 color like red + yellow + green

How to customize woocommerce for this or any plugin?

Answer (score 5):

At this point in time you can't combine multiple attributes.

Lets say you have a product (T-shirt) that comes as red or yellow or green, then your drop-down will let you select only one color(this are the product variations) you don't have a red+yellow T-shirt, only a red or a yellow T-shirt.

If you have a T-shirt that is red and yellow, then you'll have to add this as a value and you will end with a drop down that will have:

1. red
2. yellow
3. green
4. red *and* yellow

I don't think a feature that will let you combine red and green will help you as it can't guarantee that the product has those 2 colors.

As reference here it is the documentation on [Product Variations](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/).

Comment: Correct answer, this is Woo out of the box

Comment: above is just example how I want product with multi select attribute. It can be either country or other values. So user can select multiple option at the time of order. Actually I want to display product with multiple option e.g. sample categories for product so user can select multiple option at the time of order.

Comment: @steve product attributes can't be multiple because a product has specific attributes that defines it not multiple (you don't have a T-shirt in your stock that is either green or yellow or green and yellow, you have 3 products: one gree one yellow and one green and yellow). p.s. What do you mean country as an option? a has a specific country? I didn't get that, can you be more explicit?

Comment: Actually I am developing product for SEO which is directory submission as product and target as country (product attribute). So user can select multiple options (country) at time or order.

Comment: Ok, this looks different from what you initially asked. There are more ways you can achieve this, including using post_meta but you need a table with the countries... google how to use country as directory for products/posts/cpt in wordpress try some examples and if things don't work out as they should, ask on stack overflow again (but the correct question...)